# qsort type casting pointers in c

Tags: c, sorting, pointers, casting, qsort

This is a simple code to practice qsort function in C.

```
int compareF(const void *a, const void *b) {
    // return (*(int**)a)[0] - (*(int**)b)[0];  
    const int *pr1 = *(const int **)a;
    const int *pr2 = *(const int **)b;
    return pr1[0] - pr2[0];
}

int main() {
    int *array[] = {(int[]){2,2,3}, (int[]){1,2,1},(int[]){1,3,3},(int[]){0,2,3},(int[]){1,2,0}};
    qsort(array, 5, sizeof(int[3]), compareF);
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%d ", array[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
  return (0);
}
```

I don't grasp line 3 and 4 of why it is type-casted this way with pointers. This is my understanding. Firstly, it doesn't matter how we use syntax whether we set new variables to save parameters or not like those two return states are just same.
Secondly, it needs to be type cased since parameters are void type so function does not know the type. First * is for dereferencing parameter a so that It has an access to the address a. And we use int** because..?

There's 2d integer array in main function. CompareF function only takes array[0] and array[1] as parameter each time in my understanding. So I don't get why it is typed cased with two **.

Same code with only one line of code modified

```
int array[3][2]= {{1,4},{3,6},{2,8}};
```

when array is defined this way, is type casting happened in same way?

```
const int *pr1 = *(const int[])a;
const int *pr2 = *(const int[])b;
```

or

```
const int *pr1 = (const int*)a;
const int *pr2 = (const int*)b;
```

First case doesn't work and second one does. But doesn't it need * to dereference? like

```
const int *pr1 = *(const int*)a;
const int *pr2 = *(const int*)b;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters this call of qsort:

```
qsort(array, 5, sizeof(int[2]), compareF);
```

is incorrect. The third parameter is the size of elements of the array. As the type of elements of the array is `int *` then the third parameter must be `sizeof( int * )` or that is the same `sizeof( *array )`:

```
qsort(array, 5, sizeof( *array ), compareF);
```

The function `qsort` passes pointers to elements of the array to the comparison function `compareF` as pointers of the type `const void *`.

As the elements if the array have the type `int *` then a pointer to an element of the array has the type `int **`.

So within the function `compareF` you need to cast the pointers of the type `const void *` to types `const int **`. Dereferencing such a pointer like:

```
const int *pr1 = *(const int **)a;
```

you will get an element of the original array.

As the elements of the array point to first elements of compound literals that have the type `int[3]` then for example the expression `pr1[0]` within the comparison function  gives the first element of a compound literal, the expression `pr1[1]` gives the second element of the compound literal and so on.

In general using this return statement:

```
return pr1[0] - pr2[0];
```

is incorrect because the supplied expression can produce an overflow for the signed integer type `int`.

It is more interesting to sort the elements (pointers to first elements of compound literals) of the original array comparing all elements of compound literals.

Here is a demonstration program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { M = 3 };

int compareF( const void *a, const void *b ) 
{
    const int *pr1 = *( const int ** )a;
    const int *pr2 = *( const int ** )b;
    
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( i != M && pr1[i] == pr2[i] ) ++i;
    
    return i == M ? 0 : ( pr2[i] < pr1[i] ) - ( pr1[i] < pr2[i] );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int * array[] = 
    {
        (int[M]){2,2,3}, 
        (int[M]){1,2,1},
        (int[M]){1,3,3},
        (int[M]){0,2,3},
        (int[M]){1,2,0}
    };
    
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );
    
    qsort( array, N, sizeof( *array ), compareF );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", array[i][j] );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
0 2 3 
1 2 0 
1 2 1 
1 3 3 
2 2 3
```

As you can see if first elements of two compound literals are equal each other then second elements are compared and so on.

If you have a two-dimensional array declared like

```
int array[3][2]= {{1,4},{3,6},{2,8}};
```

then it means that the element type is in turn array type `int[2]`. So the function call will look like

```
qsort(array, sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array ), sizeof( int[2] ), compareF);
```

And pointer to an element of the array will have the type `int ( * )[2]`.
So dereferencing the pointer within the comparison function you will get an array of the type `int[2]` (an element of the original array) that that used as an expression is converted implicitly to pointer to its first element.

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

enum { M = 2 };

int compareF( const void *a, const void *b ) 
{
    const int *pr1 = *( const int ( * )[M] )a;
    const int *pr2 = *( const int ( * )[M] )b;
    
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( i != M && pr1[i] == pr2[i] ) ++i;
    
    return i == M ? 0 : ( pr2[i] < pr1[i] ) - ( pr1[i] < pr2[i] );
}

int main(void) 
{
    int array[][M] = 
    {
        { 1, 4 }, { 3, 6 }, { 2, 8 }
    };
    
    const size_t N = sizeof( array ) / sizeof( *array );
    
    qsort( array, N, sizeof( *array ), compareF );
    
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        for ( size_t j = 0; j < M; j++ )
        {
            printf( "%d ", array[i][j] );
        }
        
        putchar( '\n' );
    }
}
```

The program output is:

```
1 4 
2 8 
3 6
```

Pay attention to that the comparison function shall return 0 when two compared elements are equal each other. Relative to the function `compareF` it means that after the loop:

```
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( i != M && pr1[i] == pr2[i] ) ++i;
```

`i` will be equal to `M` because all elements of the compared one-dimensional arrays are equal each other.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer and correct what was wrong. Just out of curiosity, is there any reason of using enum and check if  i == M in return?

Comment: Do you mind checking my edited question if you have time?

Comment: @Hans See my appended answer.

Answer (score 3):

The compare function passed to `qsort` is called anytime any two array elements are to be compared, and it is taking the address of each of those array elements.

You have an array of `int *` that is being sorted, so the address of each of those elements has type `int **`.  That matches the type that the parameters of `compareF` are casted to.  Dereferencing those pointers then gives us a value of type `int *` which is what is actually contained in the array.

Also, the third parameter to `qsort` is not correct.  The array elements do not have type `int[2]` but instead have type `int *`.  If an `int` is 4 bytes and a pointer is 8 bytes then they happen to be the same, but you can't depend on that.

Comment: Thank you for answer! So, when array is defined like "int array[3][2]", how would it be type-casted? because defining 2d array using pointer and square brackets is different

Comment: Do you mind checking my edited question if you have time?

Comment: @Hans The array elements would have type `int[3]` so the type to cast to in the compare function would be `int (*)[3]` i.e. pointer to an array of size 3 of `int`.